# Conditional binary replacement in Pandas column with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas data frame in Python:

```
col1
----
A
B
NaN
A
A
NaN
NaN
B
C
```

I would like to replace the values so that all `A` remain `A`, all other values (`B, C` in this example) are replaced with `D`, and `NaN` remain unchanged. What is the appropriate way to do it? So that the required output is:

```
col1
----
A
D
NaN
A
A
NaN
NaN
D
D
```

I have tried these so far:

`df["col1"] = np.where(df["col1"] == "A", "A", "D")`, but this changed `NaN`s to `D` as well.

`df["col1"].replace(["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "D", "D"])` seems better, but in my real scenario there are far more non-`A` values that I want to change to `D`, so exhaustive enumeration is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].mask(df["col1"].ne("A") & df['col1'].notna(), "D")
print (df)
  col1
0    A
1    D
2  NaN
3    A
4    A
5  NaN
6  NaN
7    D
8    D
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
df["col1"] = np.where(df["col1"].isna(), np.nan,
             np.where(df["col1"].eq('A'), 'A', 'D'))
print (df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to update the values that are not A nor NaN:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].ne('A')&df['col1'].notna(), 'col1'] = 'D'
```

Output:

```
  col1
0    A
1    D
2  NaN
3    A
4    A
5  NaN
6  NaN
7    D
8    D
```